# Creating a folder for test purpose in a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I want to create a folder in wordpress site, for putting up a new test site. It would be accessed as say www.site.com/test but wordpress is not letting me access /test and saying that "Page Not Found!".

Do I need to remove/add anything in the .htaccess? Help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you actually went through the install process of WP in your root, you will be unable to access it from /test.

However, what you can do is follow these instructions:

> Many people want WordPress to power their site's root (e.g.
>   http://example.com) but they don't want all of the WordPress files
>   cluttering up their root directory. WordPress allows you to install it
>   into a subdirectory, but have your blog exist in the site root.
>   WARNING: Multisite Users - Please Read
>
> This process is not applicable to and does not work if you have
>   enabled MultiSite. Moving a Root install to its own directory
>
> The process to move WordPress into its own directory is as follows:
>
> 1. Create the new location for the core WordPress files to be stored (we will use /wordpress in our examples). (On linux, use mkdir
>      wordpress from your www directory. You'll probably want to use "chown
>      apache:apache" on the wordpress directory you created.)
> 2. Go to the General panel.
> 3. In the box for WordPress address (URL): change the address to the new location of your main WordPress core files. Example:
>      http://example.com/wordpress
> 4. In the box for Site address (URL): change the address to the root directory's URL. Example: http://example.com
> 5. Click Save Changes. (Do not worry about the error message and do not try to see your blog at this point! You will probably get a
>      message about file not found.)
> 6. Move your WordPress core files to the new location (WordPress address).
> 7. Copy (NOT MOVE!) the index.php and .htaccess files from the WordPress directory into the root directory of your site (Blog
>      address). The .htaccess file is invisible, so you may have to set your
>      FTP client to show hidden files. If you are not using pretty
>      permalinks, then you may not have a .htaccess file. If you are running
>      WordPress on a Windows (IIS) server and are using pretty permalinks,
>      you'll have a web.config rather than a .htaccess file in your
>      WordPress directory. As stated above, copy (don't move) the index.php
>      file to your root directory, but MOVE (DON'T COPY) the web.config file
>      to your root directory.
> 8. Open your root directory's index.php file in a text editor
> 9. Change the following and save the file. Change the line that says: require('./wp-blog-header.php'); to the following, using your
>      directory name for the WordPress core files:
>      require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
> 10. Login to the new location. It might now be http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/
> 11. If you have set up Permalinks, go to the Permalinks panel and update your Permalink structure. WordPress will automatically update
>       your .htaccess file if it has the appropriate file permissions. If
>       WordPress can't write to your .htaccess file, it will display the new
>       rewrite rules to you, which you should manually copy into your
>       .htaccess file (in the same directory as the main index.php file.)

More info can be found [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

Good luck!